# Changing an anchor's class with jQuery using load and click events

Tags: jquery, onclick, onload, addclass, removeclass

I have an anchor element. The 'page-2' class calls up that page and displays it using JavaScript:

```
<a id="btn2" class="page-2">Go to page 2</a>
```

I also have a function to disable the link using class 'disabledPage2' which displays a message. When the anchor element is loaded I need the disabledPage2 class added automatically:

```
var anchorElement = $(this);
if ($(this).hasClass('disabledPage2')) { message.
    new Messi('We need your X info before we can continue.', {title:'Notice'});
    return false;
}
```

When I add the 'disabledPage2' class manually it functions properly, I just can't get the class added automatically.

Then I have a set of radio buttons:

```
<?php
   $widthArray = array(380,410,435,460,490,515);
   $x = 0;
   while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
   echo '<li>
           <label class="label_radio">' . $result['option_label'] . '
             <input type="radio" name="optionName" class="radioOff" validate="required:true" value="' . $result['ID'] . '" onclick="$(\'#swoosher\').effect(\'size\', {to: {width: '.$widthArray[$x].'} }, 500);"/>
           </label>
         </li>';$x++;}
 ?>
```

When a radio button is clicked I need the 'disabledPage2' class removed.

I tried creating a function like this to handle loading the disable class when the anchor element loads:

```
$('#btn2').load(function(){
  $('#btn2').addClass('disabledPage2');
});
```

And this one to handle the onclick event for the radio buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":input").click(function(){
    $('#btn2').removeClass('disabledPage2');
  });
});
```

I've tried to get this to work all sorts of ways and no 'solution' I've found has worked. I'm somewhat new to JavaScript and jQuery and I'm obviously not doing something right.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish what I'm trying to do or can you point me somewhere I can find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the load function from the btn2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#btn2').addClass('disabledPage2');

  //This will work when you click all input elements on your page. why not use the class (redioOdd) like this $(".radioOff").click
  $(":input").click(function(){

       $('#btn2').removeClass('disabledPage2');

  });

});
```

Comment: I had to tweak that just a bit because of the way I am dynamically loading the page content, but you got me headed in the right direction and now it's working correctly. Thank you.